# List of tuples from heirarchical nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

Having an outer list of inner elements, each said inner element being 
a flat/nested list. Each said inner list has a nesting structure that matches the inner list in the preceding outer cell. Meaning that each primitive value in a list either corresponds to a primitive value or to a list - in the following cell list (recursively applied). Thus, each inner list has a depth that is equal to or exceeds by 1 the depth of the element in the preceding cell.

(Notice that the first cell element can start as a nested list of any depth).

Example of the above:

```
[
    [[1, 2,      [3, 4]], 1           ],
    [[3, [4, 5], [6, 7]], [5, 4]      ],   
    [[5, [6, 7], [8, 9]], [7, [8, 6]] ],
]
```

It is desired to unfold the nested lists into a list of tuples, where each value is combined either with the parent value, or the corresponding list element if parent is list (with order being maintained). So for the above example list, the output should be:

```
[
(1, 3, 5),
(2, 4, 6),
(2, 5, 7),
(3, 6, 8),
(4, 7, 9),
(1, 5, 7),
(1, 4, 8),
(1, 4, 6),
]
```

Note: this question is an expansion on a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757109/create-a-list-of-tuples-from-two-nested-lists), but unlike the linked question, the desired tuples here are flat.

Comment: When the data is in a complicated structure, like this, you should fix the source :(

Comment: why `[(2,4,6),(2,5,7)]` instead of `[(2,[4,5],[6,7])]`?

Comment: @khajvah: the desired output is flat tuples,  - this is unlike the linked question, I'll edit to clarify this point. If a list has a parent primitive, each value in the list combines with the parent, if a list has a parent list, corresponding values combine.

Comment: @thefourtheye: can you please point out the issue.

Comment: One note about the question itself. I think, your reputation saves the question. If you were a new guy, you would have seen many downvotes and comments like: "Did you try anything?", "We don't do homework", "Try somehting and then ask us if you see a problem."...

Comment: @khajvah: 1. I know one way to solve it, asking is good for attracting ideas and a record for others in the future. Numerous examples on SO. 2. Not a homework, this comes up in hierarchical data representation, so the outer list in the Q is just a vector in tree in nested DB. 3.I'll add my contrib and others are welcome to do so if they desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how about this:

```
x = [
    [[1, 2,      [3, 4]], 1           ],
    [[3, [4, 5], [6, 7]], [5, 4]      ],   
    [[5, [6, 7], [8, 9]], [7, [8, 6]] ],
]

from collections import defaultdict

def g(x):
    paths = defaultdict(lambda: [])

    def calculate_paths(item, counts):
        if type(item) is list:
            for i, el in enumerate(item):
                calculate_paths(el, counts + (i,))
        else:
            paths[counts].append(item)

    def recreate_values(k, initial_len, desired_len):
        if len(paths[k]) + initial_len == desired_len:
            yield paths[k]
        else:
            for ks in keysets:
                if len(ks) > len(k) and ks[0:len(k)] == k:
                    for ks1 in recreate_values(ks, initial_len + len(paths[k]), desired_len):
                        yield paths[k] + ks1

    for lst in x:
        calculate_paths(lst, (0,))
    keysets = sorted(list(paths.keys()))
    for k in keysets:
        yield from recreate_values(k, 0, len(x))


>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(list(g(x)))
[[1, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 6],
 [2, 5, 7],
 [3, 6, 8],
 [4, 7, 9],
 [1, 5, 7],
 [1, 4, 8],
 [1, 4, 6]]
```

Works by creating a "path" for each number in the structure, which is a tuple which identifies how it fits in its particular row.

---

(Original attempt):

If it's always three levels, then something like this?

```
def listify(lst):
    max_len = max(len(item) if type(item) is list else 1 for item in lst)
    yield from zip(*[item if type(item) is list else [item] * max_len for item in lst])


def f():
    for i in listify(x):
        for j in listify(i):
            for k in listify(j):
                yield k

>>> list(f())
```

Comment: Not always three levels.  A generic list.

Answer (score 0):

This is one heck of a problem to solve :-)

I did managed to get the solution for different levels as expected. However, I made one assumption to do that:

- The last column of the input is the pointer to other columns

If that is no issue, the following solution will work fine :-)

```
input = [
    [[1, 2,      [3, 4]], 1           ],
    [[3, [4, 5], [6, 7]], [5, 4]      ],
    [[5, [6, 7], [8, 9]], [7, [8, 6]] ],
]

def level_flatten(level):
    """
    This method compares the elements and their types of last column and
    makes changes to other columns accordingly
    """
    for k, l in level.items():
        size = len(l[-1]) if isinstance(l[-1], list) else 1
        # Mostly l[-1] is going to be a list; this is for just in case
        elements = l[-1]
        for i in range(-1, -len(l)-1, -1):
            elem = l[i]
            if isinstance(l[i], int):
                l[i] = [elem] * size
            else:
                for j in range(len(elem)):
                    if not isinstance(elem[j], type(elements[j])):
                        # For a list found in elements[j], there is a int at l[i][j]
                        elem[j] = [elem[j]] * len(elements[j])
    return level

level = {}

for i in range(len(input[0])):
    level[i] = []
    for j in input:
        level[i].append(j[i])

for k, l in level.items():
    for i in range(len(l[-1])):
        level = level_flatten(level)

    total_flat = []
    for item in l:
        row = []
        for x in item:
            if isinstance(x, list):
                row += x
            else:
                row.append(x)
        total_flat.append(row)
    level[k] = total_flat

output_list = []
for i in range(len(level)):# For maintaining the order
    output_list += zip(*level[i])

print output_list
```

I know this is not a pretty solution and could be optimized further. I am trying to think of a better algorithm than this. Will update if I gets to a better solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to solve this using a 2d matrix but turned out it's simpler to iterate over the last row dividing the column segments above it:

```
def unfold(ldata):
    ''' 
    ldata: list of hierarchical lists.
    technique: repeatedly flatten bottom row one level at a time, unpacking lists or
    adding repeats in the column above at the same time. 
    convention: n=1 are primitives, n>=2 are lists.
    '''

    has_lists = True
    while has_lists:
        has_lists = False 
        for i, elm in enumerate(ldata[-1]):
            if type(elm) is list:
                has_lists = True
                ldata[-1][i:i+1] = ldata[-1][i] # unpack
                for k in range(0, len(ldata)-1): # over corresponding items in above column
                    if type(ldata[k][i]) is list:
                        ldata[k][i:i+1] = ldata[k][i] # unpack
                    else:
                        ldata[k][i:i+1] = [ldata[k][i]]*len(elm) # add repeats
    return list(zip(*ldata))            

x = [
    [[1, 2,      [3, 4]], 1           ],
    [[3, [4, 5], [6, 7]], [5, 4]      ],   
    [[5, [6, 7], [8, 9]], [7, [8, 6]] ],
]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(unfold(x))

>>>
[(1, 3, 5),
 (2, 4, 6),
 (2, 5, 7),
 (3, 6, 8),
 (4, 7, 9),
 (1, 5, 7),
 (1, 4, 8),
 (1, 4, 6)]
```